# Adding a clientside onload function to an ASP.NET control in 4.0 encodes my quotes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-4.0, html-encode

I'm trying to add a Javascript function to the onLoad event of a asp:Panel.  It goes something like this:

```
string clickFunction = "$('[id*=lblHiddenPageArray]').text('');"

PagesPanel.Attribues.Add("onLoad", clickFunction);
```

I'm attaching this function to other controls (Checkboxes and Buttons) and it's working fine.  But in the PagesPanel (my asp:Panel control) it HTMLEncodes the function.  The output source looks like this:

```
onLoad="$(&#39;[id*=lblHiddenPageArray]&#39;).text(&#39;&#39;);
```

I've tried to Server.HTMLDecode it on the assignment, but I get the same thing.  I've run into this before in .net 4.0.  Surely there's a way to escape the characters or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's proper behavior.  The attribute values are unencoded by the browser before being executed.  A simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>foo</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert(&#39;foo&#39);">
        <p>foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just in case you for some reason can't un-HTML-encode things in your head ;-), Firebug in Firefox, the WebKit inspector in Safari and Chrome, and Dragonfly in Opera will do it for you automatically.